# Amazon api keeps cancelling my request

Tags: amazon-mws

Everytime I ping amazon to get _GET_FBA_MYI_UNSUPPRESSED_INVENTORY_DATA_ I can make the request and it *SUBMITTED* for about 10 seconds then when I ping again it says cancel I have tried making the request 3 times and all of the times it seems to get cancelled.

Comment: Having some code and the coding language mentioned would help...

Answer (score 1):

You are querying too much.  For that particular report I request once an hour (the most you can) and if you get a cancel message have it wait an hour and then query again.  It is initially hard to debug so I would keep around the exports to test your other portions of your code while keep the report download code separate.